# Orders are not caneled from the cron but working fine in controller

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, cron

I am having cron which will basically fetchs pending orders and check some conditions and cancel the orders.my code is

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending');

foreach($orders as $order){
    // my code which check some conditions
     code ........

    // and variable is set to error
    if($validated == "error"){
        try {
            if(!$order->canCancel()) {
                Mage::log("Cannot Cancel",null,'neo_api.log');
            }else{
                Mage::log("Can Cancel",null,'neo_api.log');
                Mage::log($order->getStatus(),null,'neo_api.log');

                $order->cancel()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, 'Cancel Transaction.');
                $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(),'Transaction ID', false);
                $order->save();
            }
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log("ERROR: ".$e,null,'neo_api.log');
        }
    }
}
```

My orders are not canceled.

I had logged it is going into if then it is logging the messages as follows

1) Can Cancel

By same code is working when i write in the controller.

and code is not working when through cron.My code is in the Model/Observer.php

Comment: have you setup cron job in confing.xml file and also your server?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue in my local magento and everything is deleting properly by cron.

I updated your code to this:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Order extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function cancelOrder()
    {
        $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending');
        foreach($orders as $order) {
            if($order->getId() == 11)
            {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                if(!$order->canCancel()) {
                    Mage::log("Cannot Cancel",false ,'neo_api1.log', true);
                }else{
                    Mage::log("Can Cancel",false ,'neo_api1.log', true);
                    Mage::log('pos1' . $order->getId() . '-' . $order->getStatus(), false,'neo_api1.log', true);
                    $order->cancel()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, 'Cancel Transaction.');
                    Mage::log('pos2' . $order->getId() . '-' . $order->getStatus(), false,'neo_api1.log', true);
                    $order->addStatusToHistory($order->getStatus(),'Transaction ID', false);
                    Mage::log('pos3' . $order->getId() . '-' . $order->getStatus(), false,'neo_api1.log', true);
                    $order->save();
                    Mage::log('pos4' . $order->getId() . '-' . $order->getStatus(), false,'neo_api1.log', true);
                    return;
                }
            }catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::log("ERROR: ".$e,null,'neo_api.log');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

```
2015-04-09T13:42:06+00:00 EMERG (): Can Cancel
2015-04-09T13:42:06+00:00 EMERG (): pos111-pending
2015-04-09T13:42:07+00:00 EMERG (): pos211-canceled
2015-04-09T13:42:07+00:00 EMERG (): pos311-canceled
2015-04-09T13:42:07+00:00 EMERG (): pos411-canceled
```

Which advice can I give to you?

- Try make something like my script and try to skip one/two/more orders. Maybe your order has something specific which disallow magento to cancel it (even if canCancel() returns true).
- Do no call cron.php from browser if you do that.
- Try to put Mage::log dipper. Inside the method $order->cancel()